# Load any kind of data from a local file in a React app

Tags: reactjs

When I want to load some data from a local file in my React app, I use jQuery and do something like this:

```
import MyData from '../data/somefile.xyz';

// In my React component:

componentDidMount() {
    $.get(MyData, function (data) {
       // Do something with the loaded data.
    });
}
```

Is there an easier or shorter way of accomplishing the same thing? Note: The data I read could be in any format. Extra code will be usually needed to parse the loaded data.

Comment: Definitely, you need extra logic for parsing the data If you can not predict format. But I think the jQuery and $.get method are unnecessary here because of the data already available in your component with the import method.

Comment: It's not available with just the import. MyData ends up getting set to a path and not to data.

Comment: If you can use webpack and somefile.json, you will definitely get the data with the import.

Comment: Yes, but not all my data is json. For that reason, I'm looking for a generic solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't simply load data in any format with `import` unless you're importing `json` or `node module` which would be available straight away to use like:

```
import MyData from '../data/somefile.json';
```

In that case you can use `MyData` without additional requests.

As you mentioned, you're loading different file types - I can suggest the following options:

1. Convert the data to JSON format if that is possible.
2. Find a webpack-loader for your data type so webpack would parse the files.
3. Fetch the file with a request as you currently do with jQuery / [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) / [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

That seems the way you're doing this is perfectly fine. The data is loaded after component is rendered, so users can see something before you fetch and process the necessary data.